# Rails: impressionist_count on a relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I'm trying to use the [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem to track visits on a relation. My write method works well:

```
@document.publications.each do |publication|
  impressionist(publication)
end
```

I have a `has_many, :through` relation like so (simplified here but it all works fine):

```
class Document
  has_many :components, :through => :publications
end
```

I'm just running into an issue writing a query to get the relevant impressions based on a component. My failing code presently looks like this:

```
<% document.components.each do |component| %>
  <%= component.publications.where(:document_id => document.id).impressionist_count %>
<% end %>
```

I get a no method error like so:

```
undefined method 'impressionist_count' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:blah
```

I know I'm writing the failing code incorrectly but I'm struggling to find the correct way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set-up :counter_cache in your association

Watch this video, it's clearly explained http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: Yeah, that'd help to some degree, but since I can't get the count initially that'd be the first hurdle.

Comment: Have you really watch the video? There is a part about the migration that explain how to get the initial count